# Select individual column json in php

Tags: php, html, json, curl, get

```js
{
    "responseData": {
        "results": [
            {
                "title": "sobig",
                "titleNoFormatting": "test",
            },
            {
                "title": "test 2 ",
                "titleNoFormatting": "test 2sd",
            },
            {
                "title": "asdasdasda",
                "titleNoFormatting": "asdasdasd",
            },
            {
                "title": "A Warming",
                "titleNoFormatting": "A Warming",
            }

         .
         . 
         . 
         . 
            {
                "title": "last thing",
                "titleNoFormatting": "sada",
            }
        ],
```

I have json files like this.

```js
for($i=$veri1; $i <= $veri2; $i++) {
        $uri    = "http://test.com/json/".$i."/0";
        $json   = json_decode(file_get_contents($uri));

        if($json->data->price >= $nakit && $json->data->odds >= $oran)
        {
```

I'm getting some data with this code correctly from another json file.

i want get data from first `json` code, `if "title" == "sobig"` . How can I do that.

`$json->responseData->results->title == sobig` is not working. How can I get data if title is sobig

Answer (score 1):

```
$json= json_decode($response, true); 
foreach ($json['responseData']['results'] as $key => $value) {
    if ($value == 'sobig') {
        // found it
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer but, i must use with ; for($i=$veri1; $i <= $veri2; $i++) { $uri = "test.com/json/".$i."/0";; $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($uri)); if($json->responseData->results->title == sobig) {  this template.

Comment: your problem is your results are an array so you need to access an specific result. result[0]->title for example

Comment: but, i want search all "title" not one. because i will not check manual this columns.

Comment: you can loop that array, you can make a for loop and use $i to search your array result[$i]->title so you wont have to check it manually. That is what Brian was also suggesting with the foreach loop.

Comment: can you please integrate Brian's code, with my current code. because i cant integrate :(

Comment: add the part of the code where you are checking  title = sobing and i will show you how.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example to see if this may fix your issue.

```
<?php

$json = '{ "responseData": {
               "result" : [
                   { "title": "sobig" , "titleNo":"test"},
                   { "title": "loco" , "titleNo":"test"},
                   { "title": "tom" , "titleNo":"test"}
               ]
}}';

    $jsonDecoded = json_decode($json);


    foreach ($jsonDecoded->responseData->result as $key => $value) {
         var_dump($value); echo '<br>';
        if($value->title == 'sobig'){
            echo "we did it!!";
            echo "<br>";
        }
        }
?>
```

I place a couple of var dumps so you can see the stucture of your object and why you need to use the foreach